# Custom ORM in Django. Based on Entity ID & Entity Type

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

My aim is to retrieve data from different model with the reference of entity type & entity id.

Example:
I have Customer model & Address model

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    entity_type = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    entity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

for now i using raw query

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers AS cust 
     INNER JOIN addresses AS addrs ON 
     (cust.id = addrs.entity_id AND 'customer' = addrs.entity_type) 
     WHERE cust.id IN (%s)", [ids])
```

But this is not Good solution. Take too much time when ids is in thousands of range.

If is there any other way to archive those data. Then please give your solution in comments..

Comment: Congratulation, you just reinvented Django's [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) xD

Answer (score 0):

```
query_set = Address.objects.filter(
    Q(entity_type='R') | Q(entity_id=1)
)
```

Comment: It's not a good solution. It;s give only address object, I want customer object also!
You used `|` `OR` operator, We need to use `AND` operator!

Answer (score 0):

It seems awkward to manage an ID to an external entity with an "entity_id" field.  Why not use a ForeignKey field to a Customer, or in case the entity is not always a Customer, use a GenericForeignKey ?

Right now you are reinventing the wheel.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    entity_type = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Then:

```
q = Address.objects.filter(customer in cutomers_collection)
```

The doc about ForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: - `GenericForeignKey` is a good solution 
- But in my case one customer have many address, 
- If i used `GenericForeignKey` i'm not able to retrieve those multiple address object!

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    entity_type = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

data = Address.objects.filter(entity_type='customer', customer_id__in=[ids]).values('address1', 'address2', 'customer__name', 'customer__email')
```

Comment: Bro i have other model also in project like Vendor. That Vendor model also use Address model. So i can't update `entity_id` to `customer` field with foreign relation in Address model!

Comment: So what? Use another fk field for Vendor, you have no limit for that